# Rails - one table with references to two other tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I've come up with this table schema for my web app:

```
+----------+------------+------------+
| User     | Event      | Invitation |
+----------+------------+------------+
| id       | id         | id         |
+----------+------------+------------+
| email    | user_id    | user_id    |
+----------+------------+------------+
| password | start_time | event_id   |
+----------+------------+------------+
|          | end_time   | confirmed  |
+----------+------------+------------+
```

Those are three models. User can have many events and also many invitations. Event belongs to one user, invitation belongs to one user and one event.

### User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
  has_many :invitations
end
```

#### Users migration

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :email
      t.string :password
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

### Event model

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

#### Event migration

```
class CreateEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :events do |t|
      t.references :user
      t.datetime :start
      t.datetime :end
      t.string :description
      t.string :venue

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

### Invitation model

```
class Invitation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :user
end
```

#### Invitation migration

```
class AlterInvitation < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :invitations do |t|
      t.references :event
      t.references :user
      t.boolean :confirmed
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Now this is my understanding of Rails so if I'm trying to be too smart and don't follow the conventions, please let me know as I'm sure this is pretty standard schema/model setup.

When I try to do this for example:

```
u = User.first
u.events.create(start_time:DateTime.now, end_time:DateTime.now + 1)
```

It all works as expected. `user_id` is assigned to the user who created it. Now assume we have a user `u2` that has sent invitation to attend event `e1` I just created above.

```
e1 = u.events.first
u2.invitations.create(event_id:e1.id, confirmed:false)
```

When I want to reference the invitations that belong to event `e1` it does not work the way I expect it to work:

```
e1.invitations

NoMethodError: undefined method `invitations' for #<Event:0x007ff214387a08>
```

I was under the impression that the line `belongs_to :event` will enable method `invitations` for me. Can anyone help me out with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :invitations, through: :user
end
```

Comment: oh i see :) this one did the trick and does exactly what I need it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Events should `has_many :invitations` at the least, if I understand your intentions.

It seems to me at first glance that "u2" is attempting to send an invitation to event that doesn't belong to her. It says events belong to a user I think perhaps you meant that an event has many users, or did you mean an event could belong to many users? In any event I think your problem lies in your model definitions. I don't think the migrations are important, makes for a cluttered read.

Caveat: I shouldn't even be reading this right now, so this is not a comprehensive response by any means.